# T-SQL Filter on formatting

Tags: sql, t-sql, filter, format

I have a ref no. column that includes all types of formatting. I'd like to include only ref.no that have a format of xx-xxxx. I currently have

inv.ReferenceNumber LIKE '%-%'

However, I have Ref No.'s with formats x-xxxxx and xxxxx-xx. Is there a way where I can filter having results as xx-xxxx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscore matches exactly one character.

So

```
where inv.ReferenceNumber LIKE '__-____'
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm reviewing the report again and the results includes xxx-xxxxxxxxx.

Comment: Example: 092-55008015, 1001-182-701,94-94001000,P17-0011

Comment: Never mind, I had '%__-____%' I updated to '__-____'